# Javascript: setAttribute works, getAttribute fails

Tags: javascript, href, setattribute, getattribute

I have this code:

```
var object1 = getElementByID('obj1');
alert(object1.getAttribute('href'));
```

This displays correctly the URL in the href attribute of the object. But, when I try:

```
var object1 = getElementByID('obj1');
object1.setAttribute('href','someotherURL');
alert(object1.getAttribute('href'));
```

This fails. The code doesn't work on FF so I can only test it in IE, no Firebug =/. I have also tried.

```
object1.href = "someotherURL";
```

but it also fails.
Does anyone knows why I cant modify the attribute? let me know if I need to provide more information.

Regards.

UPDATE:
HTML:

```
<table class="msrs-topBreadcrumb" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>
                <div>
                    <a href="SomeURL">A Name</a> &gt;
                    <a href="AnotherURL">A Name2</a> &gt;
                    <a href="Third URL">A Name3</a>
                </div>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <span>
                <a href="URL1">A Name</a>&nbsp;|
                <a href="URL2">A Name2</a>&nbsp;|
                <a href="URL3">A Name3</a>&nbsp;|
                <a href="URL4">A Name4</a>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

FUNCTION:

```
function mySubscriptions()
{
    var mySubsObj = getElementsByClass('msrs-topBreadcrumb')[0].firstChild.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[2];
    alert(mySubsObj.getAttribute("href"));
}
```

Comment: It'd help to know what HTML element is involved!

Comment: It's `getElementById` not `getElementByID`.

Comment: Also you don't need `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` to access or modify properties like "href".

Comment: I'm sorry, this is just a sample of what the code actually does. I'll provide a more complete code.

Comment: `so I can only test it in IE, no Firebug =/.` IE has a debugger! Are you using IE7 which is the last version of a browser without the console? lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById` and it works fine:

```
var object1 = document.getElementById('obj1');
object1.setAttribute('href','someotherURL');
alert(object1.getAttribute('href'));
```

Tested in Firefox, IE and Chrome.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/zdrP9/

Comment: I agree that the code is erroneous, but it's somewhat odd that the OP got an alert that satisfied him.

Comment: Weird.  I have the exact opposite problem.  getAttribute() works, but setAttribute() on the same element that I just successfully "got" is undefined.